# How to correctly force resize in IOS using Expo ImagePicker

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

I'm developing an app in React Native using the Expo framework. In the app users can take images and they have to be resized by the user itself (note: resizing it later programmatically is not possible because I might cut off important details).

When using the Expo ImagePicker library I can give an aspect ratio and this works perfect on Android, but not on IOS. On IOS I cant select the bottom or very top of the image, just the preselected square (see screenshot below). I can move the square around but it forces itself back to the preselected area.

When selecting a picture from the image library the square selection works just fine, this only happens when taking a live picture.

Anybody experienced this or knows a fix? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
    });
```

Screenshot/behaviour:
[image: screenshot]

Tried a third-party library and adjusting the aspect ratio, both didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into it as well, and it looks like there was a [pull request](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/22512) that got pushed up and should be live now. The fix no longer forces the cropped square to go back to its initial state.

You can do this by updating `expo-image-picker` to the latest update as long as you're in Expo 49.

Yarn:

```
yarn upgrade --latest expo-image-picker
```

NPM:

```
npm update --latest expo-image-picker
```